# h2o GLM with regularization

Tags: glm, h2o

I am using the h2o package in R to fit a GLM via the `h2o.glm()` fucntion. One reasonable way to assess feature importance in a GLM with the l1 regularization penalty is to monitor the order that parameters enter the linear predictor (i.e. the model) as the l1 penalty weight decreases over each successive `lambda`. I cannot find in the h2o documentation if it possible to extract this information from a returned model object.

Does anyone know if it is possible to view the fitted model form after each successive `lambda`?

Thanks,

Comment: Very interesting. Do you have any references for this technique of assessing feature importance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get the full regularization path with `h2o.getGLMFullRegularizationPath(my_glm)` where `my_glm` is the glm you trained, just remember to set `lambda_search` equal to TRUE (i.e. `my_glm = h2o.glm(x,y,training_frame, lambda_search = TRUE`)

Comment: Great. Thank you, Lauren!